# Why am I unable to direct the audio of a video to my internal speakers?

Tags: imac, audio, vlc, cinema-display

I have an iMac connected to a Cinema Display. I recorded a video on the secondary monitor (the Cinema Display) with **OBS**. To get the audio into OBS I used the plugin **iShowU AudioCapture** and I set up a multi channel audio device in the **Audio-MIDI-Setup** of the settings of macOS to be able to listen to the audio while recording it at the same time.

(The source is a 3rd party application that delivers a stream with video and audio.)

**Now, something funny happens when I want to play the video with VLC: I can only hear the audio when I use the secondary monitor as audio device in VLC.**

I can hear a youtube video playing on my iMac (primary monitor). But I can not hear the audio channel from the recording there, regardless of the output I chose. It feels like VLC *remembered* where it recorded the audio and only plays it back on the original source. Which is (in my opinion) totally crazy.

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

My audio output options are:

- internal speakers (this is the iMac, I can listen to youtube here, but not to the VLC video)
- display audio (this is the secondary monitor, the Cinema Display)
- G533 Gaming Headset (this also works, I can hear the video over the headset)
- device with multiple outputs (this I set up for the recording to be able to listen to the audio AND route it into OBS)
- iShowU Audio Capture (some plugin necessary for OBS beeing able to listen to internal audio)